# Create a Mac single file app on Windows using python

Tags: python, windows, macos, pyinstaller, py2app

PyInstaller is not a cross-compiler, so to make a Mac OS X app it should be compiled on Mac OS X. However, I don't have access to device running Mac OS X. Is it an option to create an virtual machine on python to emulate Mac and than ran py2app? (I have never done anything like that and don't have much idea on where to start.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a virtual machine to create the executable.  I use VirtualBox to run a Linux environment for creating executables for Linux.  The same thing should work for an OS X environment, although I have never tried it.  I understand the process of setting up an OS X virtual environment on a Windows machine is a little complicated, but it can still be done.  There are guides all over the internet about VirtualBox and how to set it up and use it.

This is different from creating a virtualenv for python; which to my knowledge, cannot be used for what you are asking.